# module 'tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators' has no attribute

Tags: python, time-series, feature-extraction, tsfresh

I'm new using tsfresh, when I use the following lines, I get the extracted feature as desired

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from tsfresh.feature_extraction import ComprehensiveFCParameters
from tsfresh import extract_features
    
    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]),
                       columns=['Context ID','Time Elapsed', 'time_serie A', 'time_serie B'])
    
settings = ComprehensiveFCParameters()
kind_to_fc_parameters = {
        "time_serie A": {},
        "time_serie B": {"mean": None}
    }
    
extract_features = extract_features(df,  kind_to_fc_parameters =kind_to_fc_parameters,
                     column_id='Context ID', column_sort="Time Elapsed")
    
extract_features
```

However, when I change `{"mean": None}` by `{"absolute_maximum": None}` or `"count_above": [{"t": 0.05}]` it'won't work anymore:

> module 'tsfresh.feature_extraction.feature_calculators' has no
> attribute 'absolute_maximum'

What do I miss ?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: thank you. I tried to produce a mcve

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar issue with another calculation I chose and found it's just not in the `feature_calculators.py` (you can open it from `yourdirectory\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\tsfresh\feature_extraction`), so I did `pip install tsfresh -U` in terminal to get the latest tsfresh, checked `feature_calculators.py` again, my desired function is there and code runs fine then.